# How to get an array indexed by column name?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, pdo

I have this:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$databaseName;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);
$query = "SELECT name FROM $tableName";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stm->execute();
$array = $stm->fetchAll();
$firephp->log($array);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Result on ajax is:

```
[{"name":"mike","0":"mike"},{"name":"john","0":"john"},{"name":"tito","0":"tito"}]
```

But i want to get this:

```
{"name":[{"mike","john","tito"}]}
```

Which PDO fetch_style or what should i do in PHP to receive the string i want on jQuery?

Many thanks.

Comment: The column names are in `array_keys($row)`.

Comment: Don't call `$.parseJSON` when you do `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery does that automatically.

Comment: The `information_schema` query should work, make sure you have SELECT permission to the table.

Comment: My suggestion to use `array_keys($row)` isn't quite right, it won't work if the query returns no rows.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I reformuled my question, maybe it is more clear now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
echo json_encode(array('name' => $array));
```

Comment: It works! but first line has ")" more than it should. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the column names using PDO:

```
$col_count = $stmt->columnCount();
$col_names = array();
for ($col = 0; $col < $col_count; $col++) {
    $col_names[] = $stmt->getColumnMeta($col)['name'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying Barmar. I'm fighting with this, i didn't make yet, but i'll open another post with more simple and clear question. Thanks again.

Comment: No fair completely changing the question. :(

Comment: I know Barmar. But this is what happens: i tried to understand some PDO things, i am very newbie on this, and i'm not a pro on nothing, so, with my possibilities i tried to explain why i want, but some person down vote me. Then, i tried to ask on a new thread what i want, because i kept reading about this topic and i understand that i was wrongly asking what i want. The downvote is right. But, the system didn't let me post a new topic, saying that a bot ban me from  posting new things, because my defficient participation on this place, saying that i can revert it modifying downvote post...

Comment: So i did that precisely, trying to gain votes to ask again, and i thought that editing my initial question and being more clear maybe i can generate more votes to enable asking me again and keep learning.
I know that your answers now seems offtopic, but, friend, what can i do? I'm learning, if the system don't let me mistake, how can continue? Bad learning system to newbies, maybe only for pro's, i don't know. But not for the mass. It seems a bad politic to me, but.. well.. is not my system. I repeat.. i understood on the suggestions that i should modify my words to be an approved user...

Comment: Sorry Barmar, i see almost no other chances. I'm so newbie :/